# Suppress AndroidManifest.xml minSdkVersion related warning

Tags: android, android-manifest, suppress-warnings

As recomended here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for compatibility reasons my AndroidManifest.xml contains this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
```

This generates warning in eclipse:

> Attribute minSdkVersion (3) is lower
>   than the project target API level (4)

Are there any means to suppress this warning or get rid of it any other way? It is really annoying.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In short, there is no built-in way to do this that I know of.

[Here's](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/db35efb2cdb8c053?pli=1) a discussion from last August.

And [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/07e8c93980c8b1ab/6068a1aa85841d91?show_docid=6068a1aa85841d91&pli=1) is a Xavier Durochet's response.

It looks like you can manually remove it according to Mark Murphy's response in the first thread:

> Or, you can modify SetupTask.java, eliminate this test (lines 297-308 in 
>   the code indexed by Google Code Search), and build it into a custom 
>   version of the Android Ant extension

There is a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13905) that may deal with this, but who knows when it will be implemented.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from 2011 is no longer accurate. It was fixed in ADT 17 according to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13905).

Answer (score 0):

This warning is an usual one. I am using **minSdkVersion** to support Android 1.5 and I am building for Android 1.6 to support small screens. You can build your application with the latest Android 2.3 library, but still support a lower version.